# Unable to change decimal value in MUI v5 TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I tried to display decimal value `1.0` in the MUI5's `TextField` component. I'm able to change its value only with the icons in the `TextField` but not when I try to input any value. Backspace does not seem to work.

**Excerpt from my code**

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        id="value"
        name="value"
        type="number"
        label="Decimal Value"
        value={parseFloat(value).toFixed(1)}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui5-select-cxif9?file=/src/App.js:278-526). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting the value in `onBlur` instead of `onChange`. When you type <kbd>backspace</kbd> in `onChange` the value is `1.` but is formatted to `1.0` anyway in the next render and undo your work:

```
<TextField
  type="number"
  inputProps={{
    maxLength: 13,
    step: '1',
  }}
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onBlur={(e) => setValue(parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(1))}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Perfect and exactly what I wanted. I used it this what with formik. 
`onBlur={(e) => {
formik.handleBlur(e);
formik.values.value = parseFloat(formik.values.value).toFixed(1);
}}
`